# Laravel Passport custom validation for any /oauth/token request

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I need to validate extra fields in my `users` table before i create the requested tokens, but i can't find a simple way to do it with `Passport`.

I find similar workarunds which returns a token using `$user->createToken()` but i can't find someone covering all default `/oauth/token` options like the `refresh_token`

Also i see `Passport` have some simple ways to customize the username column and the password validation but i think this not cover my neededs.

**Update**

Im not sure if this is the best solution but in Laravel `5.8` the `passport` package have this `validateForPassportPasswordGrant()` function which allow you to add some extra conditionals before allowing the authentication process to get completed.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
    {
        if ($this->active != true) {
            throw OAuthServerException::accessDenied('The account is not active');
        }

        return Hash::check($password, $this->password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to validate a custom field on user? I have the same trouble, can't find a way to validate if my new `active` column on users table is true or false.

Comment: Yes, in this scenario `active` is a column in `users` table. You are using passport right?

Comment: yes mate, it works perfectly with your code. Now I'm trying to manage the response, I don't want to get a 401. Thanks

Comment: Well you can simply set a `return response('', 400);`(or wathever http code) but i usually try to avoid return something directly from the `models`

Answer (score 0):

In your login method

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_active' => 1, 'username' => $request->username])) {
   // create a token here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you can validate extra fields but how to run the token generator from this point, in a custom controller and get: `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expires_in`?