# Laravel 5.7, API with driver passport, can't add validation on login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 apps using the same db.

One is in PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.3, it's an entire Laravel app with views, js, all in Laravel.

The other one in PHP 7.1 and Laravel 5.7 (it's used as an API for a ReactJS app)

In the older one, my `LoginController` I have rewrite this method of `AuthenticatesUsers`:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(
        $request, 
        [
            'email' => 'required|exists:users,email,active,1|exists:users,email,access_oldmaster,1',
            'password' => 'required'
        ], 
        [
            'email.exists' => 'El nombre de usuario es incorrecto o la cuenta se encuentra deshabilitada.'
        ]
    );
}
```

This version has in it's `config/auth.php` file this:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

The validation works ok. I'm trying to implement that same validation on the newer version:

```
'email' => 'required|exists:users,email,active,1|exists:users,email,access_oldmaster,1',
```

But the newer version, has this `driver` in the config (remember that this version is an API):

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
```

So, I tried to do the same as the older version, to rewrite the `LoginController` with the same `validateLogin` method, but the API is not using it.

How could I use that validation in my API?

Comment: Check your route file. by default  `api/oauth/token` route issues the access token. Which your controller method issue the access token? You have to add validation on that method.

Comment: My routes uses the middleware `auth:api`

Answer (score 0):

As I read here:

[Laravel Passport custom validation for any /oauth/token request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56614651/3541320)

I put this method in my `User` model:

```
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    // $this->what_ever_user_propertie
    if ($this->active != true) {
        throw OAuthServerException::accessDenied('The account is not active');
    }

    return \Hash::check($password, $this->password);
}
```